# PHP refresh every few seconds produced an internal 500 error

Tags: javascript, php

The code should pick a random image from a specific folder and it's sub-folders and show it. Every few seconds it should pick another ...

The code works, but after 3 or 4 hours it overloads the server I think, because it produced an internal 500 error. Only if I exclude the script from my sites the 500 would go.

HTML / JavaScript

```
<div id="auto_load"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function() { startRefresh(); });
  function startRefresh() { 
  setTimeout(startRefresh,5000);
  $.get('img-data.php', function(data) {
  $('#auto_load').html(data); }); }
</script>
```

img-data.php

```
<?php
function getFiles($dir)
{
    static $files;

    $allowed_file_extensions = array();
    $allowed_file_extensions[] = 'gif';
    $allowed_file_extensions[] = 'bmp';
    $allowed_file_extensions[] = 'jpg';
    $allowed_file_extensions[] = 'jpeg';
    $allowed_file_extensions[] = 'png';

    $len = strlen($dir); 
    if($dir{$len-1} == '/') 
        $dir = substr($dir, 0, $len-1); 

    if(!is_dir($dir)) 
        return false; 

    $open = @opendir($dir); 

    if(!$open)  
        return false;

    while($file = readdir($open)) {         
        if($file == "." || $file == "..")     
            continue;

        if(is_dir($dir.'/'.$file)) { 
            getFiles($dir.'/'.$file); 
        }

        $e = explode('.', $file); 
        $ext = $e[ count($e)-1 ];

        if(strpos($file,'320'))

        if( is_file($dir.'/'.$file) && in_array($ext, $allowed_file_extensions) ) { 
            $files[] = $dir.'/'.$file; 
        }
    }
    return $files;
}

$files = getFiles('<FOLDER>'); 
$rand = mt_rand(0, count($files)-1);

echo '<img  src="<WEBSITE>'. $files[ $rand ] .'" max-width="100%" height="auto" />';

?>
```

Any suggestions? Manual entering of the pictures and processing through javascript is no option, because in the folder are 600-700 Pictures.

Comment: is it the Ajax or the the the subsequent `<img>` that produces the 500 response? Once it occurs, does it always occur from then on or is it an intermittent problem

Comment: Could it be that you may be entering a folder that does not have any images in it yet? The "if(!$open)  return false;" line looks suspicious, which if true is not safeguarded...

Comment: The code works properly for 3-4 hours. It does show one picture (from the folder full of pictures) and change it every 5 seconds. After 3-4 hours then, the server have an 500 internal error for **all php-scripts**. Maybe my poster prevents his servers from power-hungry scripts?

Comment: I mean hoster, not poster ^^

Comment: A 500 error always means you should look in your web server's error log. Make sure error reporting is turned all the way up - at the top of your script `error_reporting(E_ALL);` Normally I'd suggest also using `display_errors`, but that is difficult to work with on an ajax script. The error log should have full details.  Probably it's a logic issue, reading past the end of the array or similar.

Comment: Or possibly a problem with the recursion.